# How to insert DB data to textarea field by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I've been struggling for some weeks with this problem. Look, I've got a page with a nice table, that is dynamic with the help of jquery.

[image]

Blue button (which's input[submit]), reacts on click and opens additional area on the right. 
All data in the table is an output from a Database. My DB looks like this:

[image: DB screenshot]

And here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">      
<title>Problem Solver</title>
<link href="other/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"></head>
<body>
<!-- -------------------upper navigation------------------------------ -->
    <div class="container-fluid">   
        <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.html">F.A.Q</a></li>
            <li><a href="tech.html">Technician</a></li>
            <li><a href="da.html">Delivery Analyst</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form action="#.php" method="post" name="search_form" class="navbar-form navbar-right" >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." name="search_field">
          </form>
        </nav>
        <!-- -----------------------RESULTS' TABLE--------------------------->
        <div class="row">                       
            <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 main myTableBlock">
                <h2 class="sub-header">Results:</h2>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <?php 
                        $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:myDB2");
                        $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM myData");
                        $query->execute();
                        $result = $query->fetchall(); 
                        echo 
                            "<table class='table table-striped table-hover' name='results_table'>
                           <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Incident Number</th>
                                    <th>Type of problem</th>
                                    <th>Subject of problem</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>Current Status</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>"
                            ;
                            foreach($result as $row)
                            {
                          echo "<tr class=".$row['ID']." >";
                          echo "<td>" . $row['incident_number'] . "</td>";
                          echo "<td>" . $row['incident_type'] . "</td>";
                          echo "<td>" . $row['incident_subject'] . "</td>";
                          echo "<td>" . $row['incident_time'] . "</td>";  
                          echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
                          echo "<td>" ."<form action='myOpennerOutput.php' method='GET'>"."<input type='hidden' name='my_inc_number' value=". $row['incident_number'] .">"."<input type='submit' name='trigger' value='Show Actions' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapseExample' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='collapseExample'>". "</form>". "</td>";

                        }
                          echo "</tr>";
                          echo "</tbody>";
                          echo "</table>";

                    ?>      


                </div>
            </div>  
            <!-- ---------------------------------OPENNER BLOCK --------------->

            <div class="col-md-2 sidebar myOpenner col-md-pull-1 col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-pull-1 col-xs-2 col-xs-pull-1">
                <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                    <div class="well">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                                <form action="#.php" method="post">
                                    <label id="incident_number">Incident nr.:</label>
                                    <textarea name="actionsByTech" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Technician's actions:"></textarea><br>    
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea name="da_description" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="DA's description:"></textarea></br>                                 
                                    <div class=" col-md-12 text-center">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
                                    </div>                                  
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>  

            <!-- ----------------OPENNER END ------------------>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="other/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

MY PROBLEM: I want, to get 'action' from myActions table in Data Base, and put in to the field from right clicking the Blue button "Show Actions". Every action is connected with different rows on site. So, first row has Incident number 999, and I want to get actions from that record in DB, and put it to field on the right. I would appreciate if you could help me with that. Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried it yourself or want to hire a developer?

Comment: Right! what you have tried so far?

Comment: Currently I have some problems with my blue button - it has bootstrap class data-toggle:collapse, which makes it impossible to use type[submit] - because there are two actions. So there are only two solutions for now : I have to delete my type[submit] - then I can't send any data, or delete data toggle - then i can't open the field from the right

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            Problem Solver
        </title>
        <link href="other/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- -------------------upper navigation------------------------------ -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">F.A.Q</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tech.html">Technician</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="da.html">Delivery Analyst</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form action="#.php" method="post" name="search_form" class="navbar-form navbar-right" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." name="search_field">
                </form>
            </nav>
            <!-- -----------------------RESULTS' TABLE--------------------------->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 main myTableBlock">
                    <h2 class="sub-header">
                        Results:
                    </h2>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <?php 
$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:myDB2");
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM myData");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchall(); 
echo 
    "<table class='table table-striped table-hover' name='results_table'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Incident Number</th>
<th>Type of problem</th>
<th>Subject of problem</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Current Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>"
    ;
foreach($result as $row)
{
    echo "<tr class=".$row['ID']." >";
    echo "<td>" . $row['incident_number'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['incident_type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['incident_subject'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['incident_time'] . "</td>";  
    echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" ."<input type='submit' name='trigger' value='Show Actions' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapseExample' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='collapseExample' onclick='refreshOpenner(".$row['incident_number'].")'>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
                        ?>      
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ---------------------------------OPENNER BLOCK --------------->
                <div class="col-md-2 sidebar myOpenner col-md-pull-1 col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-pull-1 col-xs-2 col-xs-pull-1">
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                        <div class="well">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                                    <form action="#.php" method="post">
                                        <label id="incident_number">Incident nr.:</label>
                                        <textarea name="actionsByTech" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Technician's actions:"></textarea>
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                        <textarea name="da_description" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="DA's description:"></textarea>
                                    </br>                                 
                                    <div class=" col-md-12 text-center">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ----------------OPENNER END ------------------>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="other/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function refreshOpenner(incidentNr)
            {
                $('#incident_number').text('Incident nr.: ' +incidentNr);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```